# How to synchronize the following scenario

Tags: c, winapi, synchronization

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.  Right now you'll see, if you run this, that the example takes a little more than 10 seconds to complete.  It should take less than 2 seconds.  The problem is that there is a race condition.  The loop takes too long and the SetEvent occurs before the WaitForSingle object can get it.  What would be nice is if the event could trigger but the WaitForSingleObject could still know it triggered somehow.
What happens here is that data is generated which could take a long time.  That data is then sent across the network which could take even longer.  So I want to queue data to be sent then be about my merry way while another thread picks up the data and sends it out.  That way I can queue infinitely until I have nothing left to do and then the thread joins to the sending thread until it's finished sending out all the network data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PIPE_NAME "\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe"

void copy_protocol_buffer(struct protocol_buffer *in, struct protocol_buffer *out);
DWORD PipeClientStartSendBufferThread(struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings, LPDWORD lpThreadId);
DWORD InitializeClientPipeSettings(struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings);
void initialize_protocol_buffer(struct protocol_buffer *protocol_buffer);

struct protocol_buffer {

    size_t length;
    size_t location;
    int data_type;
    char *data;
    struct protocol_buffer *next;
};

struct client_pipe_settings {
    HANDLE hPipe;
    LPCTSTR name;
    DWORD pipe_timeout;
    HANDLE write_event;
    struct protocol_buffer *fifo;
    HANDLE send_thread;
};


DWORD WINAPI PipeClientSendThread(LPVOID client_pipe_settings_object) {

    struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings = (struct client_pipe_settings *)client_pipe_settings_object;

    struct protocol_buffer *buf = NULL;

    while(1) {
        WaitForSingleObject(pipe_settings->write_event, 10000);

        if (buf == NULL) {
            buf = pipe_settings->fifo;
        } else {
            struct protocol_buffer *fifo_protocol_buffer = buf->next;
            free(buf);
            buf = fifo_protocol_buffer;

            if(buf->length == 0)
                //signal to quit
                return 0;
        }

        //Send data over the network
        Sleep(500);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD PipeQueueBuffer(struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings, struct protocol_buffer *buf)
{
    struct protocol_buffer *out_protocol_buffer = (struct protocol_buffer *)malloc(sizeof *buf);

    if(out_protocol_buffer == NULL)
        exit(1);

    copy_protocol_buffer(buf, out_protocol_buffer);

    if (pipe_settings->fifo == NULL) {
        pipe_settings->fifo = out_protocol_buffer;
    }
    else
    {
        struct protocol_buffer *last_protocol_buffer = pipe_settings->fifo;
        while(last_protocol_buffer->next != NULL)
        {
            last_protocol_buffer = last_protocol_buffer->next;
        }
        last_protocol_buffer->next = out_protocol_buffer;
    }

    if(!SetEvent(pipe_settings->write_event))
        return GetLastError();

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}



int main(void) {
    struct client_pipe_settings pipe_settings;
    InitializeClientPipeSettings(&pipe_settings);

    DWORD dwThreadId = 0;

    PipeClientStartSendBufferThread(&pipe_settings, &dwThreadId);

    //Generate data which could take a while
    Sleep(1000);
    struct protocol_buffer buf;

    initialize_protocol_buffer(&buf);

    buf.length = 5;
    buf.data = (char *)malloc(5);
    buf.data[0] = 'b';
    buf.data[1] = 'l';
    buf.data[2] = 'a';
    buf.data[3] = 'h';
    buf.data[4] = '\0';

    PipeQueueBuffer(&pipe_settings, &buf);

    Sleep(100);
    PipeQueueBuffer(&pipe_settings, &buf);

    buf.length = 0;

    PipeQueueBuffer(&pipe_settings, &buf);

    WaitForSingleObject(pipe_settings.send_thread, 100000);

}

DWORD InitializeClientPipeSettings(struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings)
{
    pipe_settings->write_event = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    if(pipe_settings->write_event == NULL)
        return GetLastError();

    pipe_settings->hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    pipe_settings->fifo = NULL;

    pipe_settings->send_thread = NULL;


    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD PipeClientStartSendBufferThread(struct client_pipe_settings *pipe_settings, LPDWORD lpThreadId)
{
    HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, PipeClientSendThread, pipe_settings, 0, lpThreadId);

    if(h == NULL)
        return GetLastError();

    pipe_settings->send_thread = h;

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

void copy_protocol_buffer(struct protocol_buffer *in, struct protocol_buffer *out) {
    out->data_type = in->data_type;
    out->length = in->length;
    out->location = in->location;
    out->next = in->next;

    out->data = (char*)malloc(in->length);
    if (out->data == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    memcpy(out->data, in->data, in->length);
}

void initialize_protocol_buffer(struct protocol_buffer *protocol_buffer)
{
    protocol_buffer->data = NULL;
    protocol_buffer->length = 0;
    protocol_buffer->location = 0;
    protocol_buffer->next = NULL;
    protocol_buffer->data_type = 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to do in this example is free the memory.  Pretend I did.

Answer (score 1):

You mechanism is simply wrong. It isn't about a SetEvent that comes to early.

If the Event is set, it might be set "more than once". PipeClientSendThread should wait for the event, and if the event is set it should send all elements that have reached the queue. You code post 3 elements into the queue, but the event is set once, the thread runs and sends only one element a time, than the the next elements are only send when the timeout is reached....

Also you have a massive problem. You queue must be protected by a critical section or a mutex. You modify and loop over elements in the queue while another thread is also reading and modifying the queue.

Use a crtical section and a std::queue... this will also help you to get rid of the memory free/malloc stuff.

Comment: If I put a CriticalSection around the dequeue, between the end of the CS and the event, there may be another SetEvent that occurs.  Also, SetEvent is running each time something is queued so it should be executed three times.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: NO! SetEvent called three times. So it is signaled again when it is already in a signaled state. There is no count for the event!
You need a critical section around putting something in the queue and retrieveing. A new event wouldn't be a problem. You need a loop around sending all data that is already in the queue!